# fetch value from a particular MS access field

Tags: excel, vba, macos, ms-access

I want to fetch data from the Access database to excel textbox using VBA. Previously when my data was in an excel table. I used something like this:

```
id=cells(1,1).Value

For i=1 to 100
    If cells(i,"A").value = id Then
        userform1.textbox2.value=cells(i,"B").value
        userform1.textbox3.value=cells(i,"C").value
    End If
Next i
```

Now I moved my data to access database, I need to get data using record set and I need a to find the last value in id field .

Comment: Why continue using Excel? Open connection to Access and open recordset with aggregate SQL statement. Access records do not have inherent order like Excel rows. Order is determined by index and sort criteria. There is a `Last()` aggregate function but not entirely reliable. By 'last' do you mean maximum value? SQL statement like: `SELECT Max(ID) FROM tablename`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple example of establishing connection to Access and pulling data with a recordset:

```
Dim con As New Connection
Dim rs As New Recordset
con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
           "Data Source=yourpath\yourfilename.accdb;"
rs.Open "SELECT Max(ID) AS MaxID FROM yourtablename", con
Debug.Print rs!MaxID
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,but how can i get it to the textbox in an userform

Comment: Try `userform1.yourTextboxName.value = rs!MaxID`.

Comment: What error message? Are you able to pull value and Debug.Print it? If you can do that then should be able to set textbox with it same as value from a Cell. However, I've never used forms in Excel so I could be way off.

Comment: Sorry,it worked the first time ,issue was with naming of field